# Calculating transform CSS params depending on the child's index

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transforms

I'm trying to get each child of a div translated a different percent:

```
#letters:nth-child(n){
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform: translateX(calc(n*10%));
    transition-delay: calc(n*200ms);
}
```

None of `transform` and `transition-delay` seems to work (the delay is equal for all the letters), but the value of `transform` also returns an error `mismatched parameters (). How to fix it?

Comment: Is that even a thing, that you can use the `n` from `:nth-child(n)` as a "variable" for _any_ such calculations ...? Never seen that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer using a CSS variable:

```css
/* somewhere in base.css to number of maximum children you want to handle, could be generated with SASS for example */

:nth-child(1){
  --child-index: 1;
}

:nth-child(2){
  --child-index: 2;
}

/* your current CSS */
li{
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--child-index)*10%))
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I'm the first child</li>
  <li>I'm the second child</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the near future (https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4559#issuecomment-1642880894) you can do this:

```css
#letters * {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: translateX(calc(sibling-index()*10%));
  transition-delay: calc(sibling-index()*200ms);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use the `n` from `nth-child()` as you intend in CSS as it is not a numerial value you can use in `calc()`.
The only way to achieve your aim (until the `sibling-index()` is implemented, see the [answer by Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76737121/1811992)) is to **manually set each child it's own properties** like this :

```
.letters:nth-child(1){
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform: translateX(calc(1*10%));
    transition-delay: calc(1*200ms);
}

.letters:nth-child(2){
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform: translateX(calc(2*10%));
    transition-delay: calc(2*200ms);
}
...
```

You could use a **CSS preprocessor** to generate such code (ex: SCSS or LESS).
Here is what it could look like with [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) :

```
$letters : 50;

@for $i from 1 through $letters {
  .letters:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform: translateX($i*10%);
    transition-delay: $i*200ms;
  }
}
```

That would generate the CSS for 50 `.letters` elements.

*On a side note, your CSS code seems to imply you have several elements with the id `#letters` in your HTML. ids should be unique in a HTML document. That is why I used a class instead of id in my examples.*

Comment: Why does it imply several elements? The "letters" id is a group in the SVG. This group consists of paths, and each path has a separate id.

Comment: @Malvinka because you used `#letters:nth-child(n)` in your given example ...? What would be the point of applying `:nth-child(n)` in the first place, if there _can_ be only one element? If this was supposed to apply to children or descendants of `#letters`, then the selector would have to be something like `#letters > :nth-child(n)` or `#letters :nth-child(n)`